# mongodb mapreduce aggregation solution or merge into alternative

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Below is the logic that I am trying to implement but I am finding it really difficult to figure out a way with MongoDB/ Node.js app

```
Data: country, state, val1
```

I need to compute mean and std. deviation using the below formula. I checked other stack overflow posts but the std dev formula that i am working is not the same:

```
for each row -> group by country, state
    mean = sum(val1)/count -> 
for each row ->
    deviation += Math.pow((val1 - mean), 2)
for each row -> group by country, state
    std dev = Math.sqrt(dev/ count)
```

the problem is with the way deviation needs to be computed. It looks like I need an aggregation for Mean before computing the deviation/ std dev through Map reduce which I dont find a way to compute. Could anyone suggest a way to do this?

If it is not possible, do we have a way to issue an update statement in mongodb similar to the below traditional merge query? I shall update the mean value for all the rows and would later invoke Mapreduce for the deviation/std dev.

```
merge into Tbl1 a using
  (select b.country, b.state, sum(b.val1)/count(b.val1) as mean
     from Tbl1 b
     group by b.country, b.state) c
on (a.country = c.country and 
    a.state = c.state)
when matched
then update
       set a.mean = c.mean
```

I am pretty new to the nosql and nodejs and it would be great if you guys could suggest a solution/ alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, computing standard deviation using map-reduce is tricky as you need to compare each data value to the mean in the traditional algorithm.

Take a look at this solution based upon the parallel calculation [algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Parallel_algorithm): https://gist.github.com/RedBeard0531/1886960

Comment: Thanks again Johnny! the parallel calculation algorithm and the github sample just produces the same result as the traditional std dev logic that i was looking for!